# Remove query results with having

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query like the following:

```
select aaa,
 count(condition_1),
 count(condition_2),
 count(condition_3)
from DB
where ...
group by 1,
order by 1
```

The above will return four columns. Is it possible with a having statement to suppress some of the fields in the results but return all the rows that the original script would produce.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If you don't need some columns - just don't `SELECT` them (captain)

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve, when you say you want to suppress some of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to "suppress" field values (and i assume that you're really looking to return 0 in that case, since the fields aren't going away as long as they're in the select) based on some criteria but return all rows, you could try the following:

```
select aaa,
case when count(condition_1) > 1 then count(condition_1) else 0 end as count_1,
case when count(condition_2) > 1 then count(condition_2) else 0 end as count_2,
case when count(condition_3) > 1 then count(condition_3) else 0 end as count_3
from DB
where ...
group by 1,
order by 1
```

obviously modify the case statements to reflect the values you wish to return, with all others being 0

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean but, from my understanding you are trying to group your results based on a single column's count. If that's right, then the code you need would be along the lines of

```
select aaa,
 count(condition_1) as count_1,
 count(condition_2) as count_2,
 count(condition_3) as count_3
from DB
where ...
group by 1,
order by 1
having count_1 > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't suppress columns (fields) and keep all the rows.

Any filtering (WHERE, HAVING etc) will apply only to rows.

You could do this

```
select
    aaa,
    case
        when somecondition then count(condition_1)
        when somecondition then count(condition_2)
    end as thecount,
    case
        when somecondition then '1'
        when somecondition then '2'
    end as thecountofwhat

from mytable
where ...
group by aaa,
order by aaa
```

Note: don't use ordinals in GROUP BY or ORDER BY. Bad practice. And only MySQL allows such nonsense in the GROUP BY.